# How to send HTTP post request using spring

Tags: spring

What configuration do i need to send HTTP post request through spring. I am using java application , it's not a web project. Can i use spring to send HTTP post request? I google it but most almost all examples are using spring MVC. Can i use just spring to send HTTP post request ?

I found this bean on net but I don't know what to do after it. I am using spring3.2 and this post i think is of year 2008...

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.springbyexample.httpclient.HttpClientTemplate">
    <property name="defaultUri">
        <value><![CDATA[http://localhost:8093/test]]></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try using jersy https://jersey.java.net/

Comment: if Spring is not obligatory, than use Apache HTTP client

Comment: your solution is REST or SOAP api

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Spring 3.0+, it will be better to use `RestTemplate` for sending HTTP requests. Once you wire the [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) ([API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)), you can use different methods in it to send different types of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Spring just to issue a HTTP post, see this post: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

And yes you can use Spring in a non-web application / command line application. Just create an instance of ApplicationContext (eg: ClassPathApplicationContext with path to your beans xml configuration injected)